# Lambda is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am following AWS Cognito and API Gateway tutorials from [part1](https://medium.com/@houzier.saurav/aws-cognito-with-python-6a2867dd02c6), [part 2](https://medium.com/@houzier.saurav/authentication-with-cognito-202977f8d64e) and [part 3](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/private-api-endpoints-with-api-gateway-authorizers-and-cognito-249c288b0ab8).

From part 1, I created the following lambdas:

1. signup
2. confirm signup
3. forgot pwd
4. resend verify code
5. successful registration

and each of these lambdas has a separate role automatically generated for them.

From part 2, I connected these lambdas to various API endpoints in API Gateway, with the `/login` route being connected to the "successful registration" lambda.

From the part 3 tutorial, I created a `refresh_access_token` lambda function and also the `test_user`. Then, in the API Gateway, I created a new resource `/user/test-user` and added a `GET` method, which I connected to the `test_user` lambda. (The `refresh_access_token` isn't connected to a route).

After that, I go to the **Create a New authorizer** section from part 3, and when I run the `/login` route, I end up getting the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2020 19:42:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 423
Connection: close
x-amzn-RequestId: 86e522e3-1843-4c05-8d70-c6731c5f110f
x-amz-apigw-id: VFezhGcvFiAFqOQ=
X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-5f987816-65f557256f2ccd172032ff15;Sampled=0

{
  "message": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the AdminInitiateAuth operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/cognito-successful-registration-role-ck5hni20/cognito-successful-registration is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxx:userpool/eu-central-1_xxxx,
  "error": true,
  "success": false,
  "data": null
}
```

The **cognito-successful-registration-role-ck5hni20** just has **AWSBasicExecutionRole** attached to it and the trust relationship looks as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: Add `cognito-idp: AdminInitiateAuth` action to your allow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Locate the role `cognito-successful-registration-role-ck5hni20` in AWS console. Once you do this, you can add an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) to in the following form:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",
            "Resource": {
                 "AWS": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxx:userpool/eu-central-1_xxxx"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

or use more general form:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You're always a saviour :D. Just one question: can I change the action from `cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth` to `cognito-idp:*` to allow for all the actions?

Comment: accepted the answer :) For cognito-idp, is there a pre-existing policy that can be attached directly? If not, should a policy be created for it for future use?

Comment: @Junkrat There are existing policies such as `AmazonCognitoPowerUser` or `AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities` and others, but you would have to inspect their permissions in AWS console to check if they are suited for your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are new to AWS like this, here is a more detailed solution:

1. go to your lambda function
2. Under configuration, click permission, and then you'll see Execution role and the corresponding role name.
3. click on role name
4. then edit the permission and add a new inline policy, as suggested by @Marcin.
5. finally, click create policy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `AdminInitiateAuth`, but mine was slightly different: `Auth flow not enabled for this client`.

I could not solve the issue with any kind of role, the problem was not with the function but with the Cognito **client** used in the login handler.

The solution was to go to the Cognito User Pool in the AWS Console, then to 'App clients' and to check the boxes for `ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` and `ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH`